# Most Significant Carrier rule for cabin luggage

Tags: airlines, regulations, hand-luggage

Does the Most Significant Carrier (MSC) rule apply to cabin luggage including carry-on and personal items?

Is there anything to do in order to take more than one airline in the route normally allows, when another airline is the Most Significant Carrier?

Suppose I am flying a segment with a small allowance, how do I demonstrate that another carrier's more generous rule should apply?

Comment: @pnuts - Done and I don't know. I found a statement in [COPA Airline's site](https://www.copaair.com/en/web/us/baggage-policy) which refers to the MSC but it does not name a resolution by number or organization.

Comment: There's (almost) always more room for luggage in the hold but the same can't be said of the cabin. While obviously often the luggage rules are only for price gauging, not always. It's possible you are flying on a small plane, plain and simple. So it makes total sense to leave the cabin luggage rules up to the operator.

Comment: The MSC rules applies to checked baggage because it is checked once for the entire series of flights and there needs to be a standard policy as to which airline's baggage rules apply.  Carry on baggage however boards each flight separately in your care and is therefore subject to each airlines rules.

Comment: @Tom - It also makes it a pain because I have a single ticket covering 7 airlines and I had to analyse everyone's rules to get to the smallest common denominator. It would be very nice of passengers if they could all agree and bags would always fit. Currently some that I own are 0.5" to wide for one airline, 2" too short for another and fit well in most others despite never have any problems fitting it under a seat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the Most Significant Carrier (MSC) rule apply for cabin luggage including carry-on luggage and personal items?

No. For details of IATA Resolution 302 [see](http://www.ludd.ltu.se/~pat/BC/IATA-baggage.pdf).

> Is there anything to do in order to take more than one airline in the route normally allows when another airline is the most significant carrier?

No.