# Student Baggage Policy Extension to Delta Airline

Tags: delta-air-lines, air-india, student-visas

I am a student from India travelling with below itinerary on a single PNR.

- New Delhi India to New York USA - Air India 101
- New York USA to Jacksonville USA - Delta Airline 1420

Air India allows one free additional check-in baggage for students upon showing the student visa at the departure airport. Can I use this benefit for Delta Airline leg as well or do I need to pay for the additional baggage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Baggage rule for international traveller on domestic flight](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103475/baggage-rule-for-international-traveller-on-domestic-flight) See the answer posted by Itai.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.